# Nested function in Javascript not getting recognised

Tags: javascript, function, nested, return

Below is the simple nested function I wrote in Javascript

```
function outside(x) {
    function inside(y) {
      
      console.log(x + y);
    }
   return inside ;     //
  }
  const fnInside = outside(3); 
  const result = fnInside(5);
```

The programme is behaving normally. However , if I remove `return` statement from line 5 , it throws below error.

[image]

I am new to Javascript.Can anyone please explain to me why return statement removal makes programme behave like this ?

Thank You

Comment: just add `console.log(fnInside)` right before the `const result = ` line.

Comment: Because then `outside` returns nothing, instead of the function `inside`..  But you can just do -> `return function inside(y) {`  You could also do -> `const outside = x => y => console.log(x + y)`

Answer (score 2):

If you remove `return` you will not return the `function` reference and the outer function will be `void` function which will return `undefined` by default, and when you try to execute `undefined` as a function it will give an error that `undefined is not a function` to be executable.

Same as the snippet below.

```js
const undefinedValue = undefined;

undefinedValue()
```